# iRobot Create 2 sensors

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

Can someone please provide me with a list of sensors on the create 2?  I am hoping to get one soon, but want to be sure it has ultrasonic sensors and not just bump sensors before I do.

Comment: Is this information not available in the iRobot Create 2 manual?

Answer (score 4):

The Roomba does not have ultrasonic sensors, but it does have quite a few infrared proximity sensors.  The [Open Interface Spec](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) calls it the "light bumper".

Package IDs 46-51 (pages 30 and 31) describe the different light bumper IR sensors.  They return a 12 bit number (0-4095) which will roughly correspond to distance to an object.  However it is highly dependent on the object's material.  The "light bumper" packet (45) contains a binary version of all the light bumper sensors together.  I don't know what threshold is used for this.

Comment: Can these be used as rangefinders or only as binary "bump" sensors?